# What causes file managers to show drives?

Tags: drive, filemanager, thunar

What forces a file manager to show unmounted partitions in the left pane?

That is - what process is it that causes filemanagers to show drives - it's not fstab - I can show that here, I know that inserting a mountable volume makes it show.

I'm trying to understand what it is that actually gives the filemanager the signal to show the partition in the first place.

Comment: My impression is that it shows all partitions that have a filesystem and are not already mounted by the `fstab`. You can find this partitions in `/dev` and they are named in the pattern `sdxn` where x is a letter (describing the physical drive) and n is a number (describing the partition number on that drive). E.g. if you only have a sda drive and plug in an USB-Stick you can see an sdb drive showing up in `/dev`.

Comment: I know that. I am trying to find WHAT causes them to show, not what they might get called ;)

Comment: Like I said: I think it's if they have a filesystem and are not already mounted. Or are you looking for the events/system calls that lead nautilus to show new devices when they are plugged in? EDIT: I see you've edited your question. Now it's clear what you mean ;-)

Comment: All that's been edited today is tags ;)

Comment: Oh, must have read it wrong then. Sorry!

Comment: That's ok - I've done the same myself :)

Comment: "The partition has to be mountable by the user. In practice that means either on a removable volume or listed in the /etc/fstab" Not true in Ubuntu 13.10 with Openbox and thunar. Thunar as user shows all the formatted partitions. The only one in fstab is / itself. Thunar as root oddly enough doesn't show them. Seems backwards, doesn't it? I'm trying to figure out how to make thunar as root behave the same way as thunar as user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of the program causing Nautilus to show partition in the left side bar is `gvfs-gdu-volume`. To kill this process, run this command to see the PID of the program

```
sudo ps -e | grep gvfs-gdu-volume
```

In my system, the output is

```
 6642 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gdu-volume
```

So, I know the PID is `6642`, it may vary by time to time.

Kill that process with

```
sudo kill -9 PID-of-gvfs-gdu-volume.
```

**Or** as a one liner, try this

```
sudo kill -9 `ps -e | grep gvfs-gdu-volume | cut -f 2 -d ' '`
```

Open nautilus to see the magic !

[image: image of nautilus in Ubuntu 12.04]

This image is from thunar in Xubuntu 12.04 LTS.

[image: thunar file manager in Xubuntu 12.04]

**Note:** The solution isn't permanent. Whenever you open a file in Gedit or something like that, The drive icon all appears again. To permanently disable this, follow the below work around.

### Workaround to disable this permanently.

Open a terminal and do this command:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor.bak
```

This command renamed the *culprit* file to show the drive icon with adding a `.bak` extension. That's it.

If you want to revert the change, use this command

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor.bak /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
```

Note: This is not a decent solution, but this works perfectly, and I am happy with this.

### My drive icon has gone, How can I mount them now

Don't cry. Here is your trusted friend terminal. Open a terminal and do this command to mount `/dev/sda1` partition. It will do what nautilus does.

```
udisks --mount /dev/sda1
```

To find the `/dev/sdaX` number of desired partition, do `sudo blkid` on the terminal.

---

### Update for 12.10

It seems Ubuntu 12.10 is using `udisks2` program and the responsible program for showing the drive icon is also changed. It is now `gvfs-udisks2-volume`. You should kill this process instead of older `gvfs-gdu-volume` program.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqoxX.png):  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIjuK.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIjuK.png

Comment: I use Xubuntu and thunar, grep for grep gvfs-gdu-volume gives nothing.

Comment: Which Xubuntu version are you using? Edit the question to reflect this. I checked on Xubuntu 12.04 with thunar.

Comment: 12.10 atm - but the question was raised with 12.04 - I booted it to see and got a response with grep gvfs-gdu-volume, when I have a bit more time I will boot to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Anwar, looks like gvfs-gdu-volume is the answer to my question then :)

Comment: We can have another look when QQ is released :)

Comment: @Elfy I just added information to handle 12.10 too.

Answer (score 0):

The partition has to be mountable by the user. In practice that means either on a removable volume or listed in the /etc/fstab.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Perhaps I didn't frame my question very well - it is kind of vague. What I'm trying to find out it is that actually causes the system to show it in nautilus for instance. I have a partition that I mount in fstab - because I use /mnt it doesn't show automatically. What part of the system is it that causes a drive to show in the filemanager before it is mounted?